# Android Picasso library not loading image from URL

Tags: android, android-studio, picasso, android-studio-3.0

For some reason Picasso is not loading image from URLs. I just see a blank white screen. 
I have already tried doing solutions to previous questions like these but nothing works for me.

Here is the Java code of Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picassoImage);
        Picasso.with(this).load("https://futurestud.io/images/books/picasso.png").into(mImageView);
    }
}
```

And here is the XML layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.sourabh.usingpicasso.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/picassoImage"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Note:-

1. I tried with different URLs but no luck.
2. I have already set the permission for Internet in Manifest.XML
3. When I chain the `error` with `Picasso.with(this).load("https://futurestud.io/images/books/picasso.png").into(mImageView)`(ie

   Picasso.with(this).load("https://futurestud.io/images/books/picasso.png")
                   .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher_background).
                   into(mImageView);

) and pass to it an Image from the drawable, the drawable image is displayed. Seems that Picasso is not loading image from URLs only.

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue on my phone. The image loads fine.

Comment: not loading on the Android Emulator Nexus API 25.

Comment: try to check on Android Real Device @SourabhKhandelwal

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://github.com/square/picasso for Picasso library in details.

Maybe you are using the previous version. Please add following line in your app level build.gradle file.

```
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
```

Then in your activity do this.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.picassoImage);
        Picasso.get()
                .load("https://futurestud.io/images/books/picasso.png")
                .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image)
                .error(R.drawable.error_image)
                .into(mImageView);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even I was facing this issue on Android Emulator (Device: Pixel 3a XL) and after like few hours trying to fix this, and then I ran the app on the real device the images were being loaded

Answer (score 0):

You should use new version : `implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'`

Old Use:

```kotlin
        Picasso.with(applicationContext).load(intent.getStringExtra(FLAG))
            .into(binding.ivCountryPoster)
```

New Use:

```kotlin
        Picasso.get().load(intent.getStringExtra(FLAG))
            .into(binding.ivCountryPoster)
```

It's worked.